# QT5.5.1 nmake - unknown flag '-' For usage error

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, qtwebkit, nmake

Greeting

I'm building `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1` For `Visual Studio 2010` but when it comes to `webkit` in `nmake` i get the following error.

```
       ( if not exist Makefile.ANGLE.DerivedSources C:\QT-Source\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\QT-Source\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\qtwebkit\Source\ThirdParty\ANGLE\DerivedSources.pri -o Makefile.ANGLE.DerivedSources ) && "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.ANGLE.DerivedSources

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        flex --noline --nounistd --outfile=generated\glslang_lex.cpp src\compiler\glslang.l
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\flex.EXE: unknown flag '-'.  For usage, try
        C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\flex.EXE --help
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\flex.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

This is how i configured it

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010 -icu -prefix C:\QT-Compile
```

Here is my Environment Variables Information

```
Environment:
    INCLUDE=
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
      C:\Hashemi\Programming\CmpiledForVS2010\icu\include
    LIB=
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib
      C:\Hashemi\Programming\CmpiledForVS2010\icu\lib
    PATH=
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools
      c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
      c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCPackages
      C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin
      C:\Ruby192\bin
      C:\Perl\site\bin
      C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin
      C:\Perl\bin
      C:\Windows\system32
      C:\Windows
      C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
      C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
      c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
      C:\Python27
      C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin
      C:\QT-Source\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1\qtbase
      C:\Hashemi\Programming\CmpiledForVS2010\icu\bin
```

Whats Wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just hit same issue (with everything checked out to be 5.6), https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47834 seems relevant (may be multiple `flex` binaries in your path, also).

Comment: bison is not in your PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded [Win flex-bison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/win_flex_bison-2.5.5.zip/download) and replaced it in GnuWin32\bin in program files and QT directory. The error is gone, Thanks to "mlvljr"

Then i got new error :

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        bison --no-lines --skeleton=yacc.c --defines=generated\glslang_tab.h --output=generated\glslang_tab.cpp src\compiler\glslang.y
'bison' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'bison' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

To fix this, I added [Win flex-bison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/win_flex_bison-2.5.5.zip/download) to `Path` environment variable.

I managed to finish my `nmake` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've installed the GnuWin32 files (C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin): "flex.exe" and "bison.exe" (and other files there) and the "winflex" files (C:\winflex): "win_flex.exe" and "win_bison.exe". All of this files are in the PATH variable (set PATH=%PATH%;C:\winflex;...).
And for correct work I did following:

> 1) rename C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\flex.exe to some unused name.
>
> 2) rename C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\bison.exe to some unused name.
>
> 3) rename C:\winflex\win_bison.exe to bison.exe.

And the flex error fixed.